# Trying to create AWS Elasticsearch cluster using serverless. Ended up with Status Code: 409; Error Code: InvalidTypeException

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, serverless

Following is a snippet from my `serverless.yml` file to create elasticsearch domain. If I comment `AccessPolicies` section, elasticsearch domain got created but it fails when I un-comment it. I want to give access to the resources of my AWS account to access elasticsearch service. Not sure what is wrong. When I explore in stackoverflow or google, I hit some results but are related to terraform.
Note: I use `serverless-pseudo-parameters` to refer to variables in `serverless.yml`.

```
EventsElasticsearchDomain:
  Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
  Properties:
    ElasticsearchVersion: 7.4
    DomainName: testevents
    ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
      InstanceCount: 1
      InstanceType: m5.large.elasticsearch
      ZoneAwarenessEnabled: false
    EBSOptions: # its expected when we use m4 or m4 InstanceType
      EBSEnabled: true
      VolumeSize: 10
      VolumeType: gp2
    AccessPolicies:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: '#{AWS::AccountId}'
          Action: 'es:ESHttp*'
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:es:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:domain/testevents/*
```

**Error**:

```
An error occurred: EventsElasticsearchDomain - Error setting policy:
  [{"Version":"2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z","Statement":[{"Action":"es:ESHttp*","Resource":["arn:aws:es:REGION:ACCNUMBER:domain/testevents/*"],"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"ACCNUMBER"}}]}] 
(Service: AWSElasticsearch; 
Status Code: 409; Error Code: InvalidTypeException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxx).
```

Comment: Still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Well, found the culprit. Its me giving the version as date object rather than a string. Changing the `Version: 2012-10-17` to `Version: '2012-10-17'` fixed the issue.

We can notice it in the error message: `"Version":"2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"`. It shows value of Version as date string, not the string that I've sent.

Answer (score 1):

You for got about `!Sub` and `$` in your policy:

```
Resource:
   - !Sub "arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/testevents/*"
```

The same for

```
    Principal:
      AWS: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}"
```

Comment: Hmm, it didn't help. I've directly pasted the values for testing and ended up in the same error.

Comment: I know this is old but this fixed my issue so thanks!